# django - manage.py error in production

Tags: mysql, django, manage.py

I have just deployed a django application for the first time using MySQL as the database. In development, I am using sqlite3 and south for migrations.

I suppose I am to use `python manage.py syncdb` then `python manage.py migrate` to initialize the database. However, when I run `python manage.py syncdb` for the first time in production, I get the following error:

> DatabaseError: relation "utils_message" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...sage"."message_type", "utils_message"."text" FROM "utils_mes...

What could I be missing? Could it be a cyclic dependency of some sort?

My INSTALLED_APPs setting looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'south', 'django.contrib.admin',  'mainapp', 'employerprofile', 'applicantprofile',
     'companies', 'postings', 'utils', 'searchjobs', 'comments', 'projectapp',
     'cart',  'applications', 'packages', 'feedback', 'cvbank', 'staffpostings',
     'logs',
     # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:                       
     # 'django.contrib.admindocs',                                                     
)
```

Comment: Have you created the database in MySQL (named as in settings.py `DATABASES['default']['NAME']) ?

Comment: Yes, the database exists, and the django db user has all rights to it.

Comment: your database contain old table schema ? Django can't update schema (ie: add new field on existing model already synced is impossible with ./manage syncdb), it can only create it from scratch (you could use South to migrate and update old schema)

Comment: There's no existing schema. The database is empty. I want to initialize the db for the first time.

Comment: It is a bad practice to use different databases in development and in production. Could you please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` and models?

Comment: @alecxe Seems I'm learning the hard way :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. It was caused by a dependency among the models.

I did a grep on `Message` and discovered that a field in a model in the `postings` app depended on an instance of the `Message` model in the `utils` app as its default value, ie:

```
from utils.models import Message
...
default_message = Message.objects.get(message_type='application-receipt-message').text
...
class Posting(models.Model):
    ....
    receipt_message = models.TextField(default=default_message)
    ...
```

So I changed the `default_message` to an empty string, did `python manage.py syncdb` followed by `python manage.py migrate`, and didn't experience any more problems.